Get title/label in other languages using APIv4?
I have a multilingual installation of CiviCRM with en_US, nl_NL, and fr_FR enabled. The civi version is 5.58.1
Basically, I want to do
select id, title_en_US, title_nl_NL, title_fr_FR from civicrm_event in my extension.
But using APIv4 I can only select "title".
\Civi\Api4\Event::get(FALSE)->addSelect('id, 'title')
This does not work:
\Civi\Api4\Event::get(FALSE)->addSelect('id', 'title_en_US', 'title_fr_FR', 'title_nl_NL')
Is there are way to also select the title in the other languages using APIv4?

You probably need to make 3 calls, and add e.g. ->setLanguage('fr_FR') to each call for each language.

That works. Thanks a lot!
